# How to detect the status code of the same page in PHP

Tags: php

I'm developing an api that can detect simultaneous request (For example 5 request is supported).

I have a sql table with rows limit and requests_made.

I have my attempt here the `sleep(30)` is just a delay for example.

```
<?php
include_once('connectdb.php');
$api_key_url = $_GET['api_key'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE api_key = '$api_key_url'";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $account1 = $row['email'];
    $requests_made= $row['requests_made'];
    $limit = $row['limit'];
}



if ($check_speed > $check_limit){
    echo"Your request couldn't be served. Your account is already running at maximum requests";
    exit();
}

mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE hash SET check_speed = requests_made + '1' WHERE email = '$account1';");

echo"Request Is Served";
sleep(30);


mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE hash SET check_speed = requests_made - '1' WHERE email = '$account1';");
?>
```

This works perfectly until the user decides to exit the tab until it finishes loading because the counter will update +1  on the requests_made. Any suggestions for these ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ignore_user_abort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) function.

Comment: Do you get any error? Check whether $conn is still a valid resource for the last update.

Comment: any other way to  limit simultaneous calls on a php api?

Comment: Depending on your needs and options available, you can configure the webserver to limit connections, you could use a different protocol (web sockets) instead of http. However, there is one more thing. You are probably hitting the execution time limit with the sleep(30): https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: is there a way to detect the status code of the page? like if(httpstatus == 200){}

Comment: Or if the tab was immediately closed?

Comment: HTTP status code is something that the server (php) sends to the client. It can be any number you want :). So checking status code on server side does not make sense in your case. Try using connection_aborted() or connection_status() php functions.